# Laravel adding Multiple yield to a single section

Tags: php, laravel

I am pretty new to laravel, basically I have 3 pages `home`, `contact` and `people`. All my app layout are in `app.blade.php` and the problem I am facing is on the `home.blade.php`. It needs to contains  contact and people page but it's not working.

Here is what I have tried:

My `app.blade.php` looks similar to:

```
</header>
<body>
    @yield("content")
</body>
<footer>
```

`contact.blade.php`:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    //contact
@stop
```

`people.blade.php`:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    //people
@stop
```

Now here I am confused.

`home.blade.php`

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
//home
@include('people')
@include('contact')
@stop
```

When I use `include` here `people` pages shows up but `contact` doesn't, and when I use `yield` nothing shows up. How should I build this page so both `people` and `contact` pages gets included as one page?

Comment: If 'people' and 'contact' are only to use them to include them at 'home', you can remove `@extends` and `@content` from both

Comment: those are pages as well so i guess it would need @extends to works when called individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achive what you want is to have the content of 'people' and 'contact' in other view. Then you will can include them in main 'people' and 'contact' views, and in any other view:

**app.blade.php**

```
..
</header>
<body>
@yield("content")
</body>
<footer>
..
```

**contact.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    @include('contact-content')
@stop
```

**contact-content.blade.php**

```
//contact
```

**people.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    @include('people-content')
@stop
```

**people-content.blade.php**

```
//people
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    //home
    @include('people-content')
    @include('contact-content')
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use @extends in your other pages like people and contact the reason is that you already using @extends app
In your home.blade.php so you will automatically get the header and footer in both the pages people and contact